# merge new data into old data by replacing old data while appending new rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data frames with the same column names. Old data frame `old_df` and the new data frame is `new_df` with 1 column as a key.

I am trying to merge the 2 data frames into a single data frame which following conditions.

1. If the key is missing in the new table, then data from `old_df` should be taken
2. if the key is missing in old table, then data from `new_df` should be added.
3. If the key is present in both the tables then the data from `new_df` should overwrite the data from `old_df`.

Below is my code snippet that I am trying to play with.

```
new_data = pd.read_csv(filepath)
new_data.set_index(['Name'])
old_data = pd.read_sql_query("select * from dbo.Details", con=engine)
old_data.set_index(['Name'])
merged_result = pd.merge(new_data[['Name','RIC','Volatility','Sector']],
                         old_data,
                         on='Name',
                         how='outer')
```

I am thinking of using `np.where` from this point onwards but not sure how to proceed. please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for match by `Name` columns:

```
merged_result = (new_data.set_index('Name')[['RIC','Volatility','Sector']]
                 .combine_first(old_data.set_index('Name'))
                 .reset_index())
```

Sample data:

```
old_data = pd.DataFrame({'RIC':range(6),
                         'Volatility':[5,3,6,9,2,4], 
                         'Name':list('abcdef')})

print (old_data)
   RIC  Volatility Name
0    0           5    a
1    1           3    b
2    2           6    c
3    3           9    d
4    4           2    e
5    5           4    f

new_data = pd.DataFrame({'RIC':range(4),
                         'Volatility':[10,20,30, 40], 
                         'Name': list('abhi')})

print (new_data)
   RIC  Volatility Name
0    0          10    a
1    1          20    b
2    2          30    h
3    3          40    i
```

---

```
merged_result = (new_data.set_index('Name')
                 .combine_first(old_data.set_index('Name'))
                 .reset_index())
print (merged_result)
  Name  RIC  Volatility
0    a  0.0        10.0
1    b  1.0        20.0
2    c  2.0         6.0
3    d  3.0         9.0
4    e  4.0         2.0
5    f  5.0         4.0
6    h  2.0        30.0
7    i  3.0        40.0
```

Comment: This was a great answer. It worked like a charm. I have spend a lot more time understanding pandas and the functions it provides.

Answer (score 1):

@jezrael's answer looks good. You may also try splitting dataset upon conditions and concatenating the old and new dataframes.
In the following example, I'm taking **col1** as index and producing results that comply with your question's rules for combination.

```
import pandas as pd
old_data = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'col2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']}
new_data = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 'col2': ['V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']}
old_df = pd.DataFrame(old_data)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
```

old_df:
[image]

new_df:
[image]

Now,

```
df = pd.concat([new_df, old_df[~old_df['col1'].isin(new_df['col1'])]], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which gives us

df:
[image]

Hope this helps.